# Seeking efficient way to pull specific vars from request into an array

Tags: php, arrays, datatable, xmlhttprequest

I'm attempting to dynamically build a PLSQL statement based on the contents of my request headers.  This is being coded in PHP.
I'm passing a long series of parameters for server-side processing using DataTables. As a result, I have close to 60 parameters being sent.
Some parameters, the ones I need to work with, can be listed multiple times in the request.

They look like this

```
oldCode=12&oldCode=14&oldCode=21&newCode=74&newCode=81
```

I want to read the request and populate two arrays, which I will use to build my where clause. Whereas, oldCode would contain 12, 14 and 21, and newCode has 74 and 81.

I've looked at filter_var_array, but it assumes the array contains only the specific elements, not a jumble like the request holds.

Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php But duplicates will need to be an array: `oldCode[]=12&oldCode[]=14&oldCode[]=21` or else you will only get the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that uses `array_reduce` to build a multidimensional array:

```
$data = "oldCode=12&oldCode=14&oldCode=21&newCode=74&newCode=81";

$result = array_reduce(explode("&", $data), function ($c, $i) {
    list($k, $v) = explode("=", $i);
    $c[$k][] = $v;
    return $c;
}, []);

print_r($result);
```

If you are only interested by some keys you can select them like that:

```
$filter = array_flip([ 'oldCode', 'newCode' ]);

$result = array_reduce(explode("&", $data), function ($c, $i) use ($filter) {
    list($k, $v) = explode("=", $i);
    if (isset($filter[$k])) $c[$k][] = $v;
    return $c;
}, []);
```

---

if your request looks like `oldCode[]=12&oldCode[]=14&oldCode[]=21&newCode[]=74&newCode[]=81` then use `parse_str` as AbraCadaver suggests:

```
$data = 'oldCode[]=12&oldCode[]=14&oldCode[]=21&newCode[]=74&newCode[]=81';

parse_str($data, $result);
```

If you want to select some keys, add:

```
$filter = array_flip([ 'oldCode', 'newCode' ]);
$result = array_intersect_key($result, $filter);
```

Comment: Casimir - This gets me very close, but not quite.  I'm getting data in the newCode, but not in oldCode, due to my request header string. It looks like this, apologies for not catching the first time, but its returning oldCode[]=1&oldCode[]=2&newCode=4. If I add multiple items, brackets are included.

Comment: With Casimar's solution I was able to come up with a full solution to my issue.  Thank you very much

Comment: @AllanL: I added the way to go for a "normal" request (i.e. with brackets for repeated var names).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the nature of your data source, but can you change the names of the fields?

If so, you can change the names/ids for your inputs:

```
<input name="person[0][first_name]" value="john" />
<input name="person[1][first_name]" value="jack" />
```

Or if you don't want to name them:

```
<input name="person[]" value="john" />
<input name="person[]" value="jack" />
```

And then POST those values:

```
var_dump($_POST['person']);
```

Credit:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#87650